# I want to host an AJAX based website on an Apache web server and host a MySql database on the same machine for about 50 concurrent users

Tags: mysql, php, ajax

The website gets its data from the MySql database.

Will a Mac Mini with 2GB Ram and an Intel Core 2 Duo do the trick?

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer this question. We have no idea what kind of CPU/RAM/DB Workload your site will be placing on the system.  Generally speaking ServerFault cannot do capacity planning for you -- You are the one who knows your environment, therefore you are the one who has to make the judgment call (either through experience, by performing empirical tests, or by massively over-speccing the system to be safe).

Answer (score 1):

simple answer: try it out!

i do run a application with average 150+ concurrent users on a **low-budget cloud-VPS** with only 1024mb Ram and it works pretty well. it depends on your hosted application.

Answer (score 1):

Giving the specs of Mac mini and 50 users, if the website isn't intensive in disk I/O and MySQL queries, yes it would work on this machine. 
There isn't a general rule of thumb that would help you know if this processor would work with 50 users, or 100 users, often you can find that system with less processing power can be enough for your website, there are times when you need to get a powerful Xeon server with 8 GB RAM and fast disk I/O for a blog, all depending on it's architecture.

If you optimize your website, MySQL database and MySQL queries, you'd be fine.

Answer (score 0):

the Mac mini will do the job but with lower speed than a dedicated system for hosting apps.
also the bandwidth and response to request will be more sensible lower than a VPS or host.

also you have to care about the power supply and system crash and setting firewall and very different networking issues which will be nearly omitted in VPS and Hosting-Companies
but if you want to serve an App for some Private persons in a private network that is a Generous setup. :)